# Render a Calendar with Timeslots and Overlapping Appointments

Tags: c#, .net, list, time

I'm struggling to get my head round this one.

I have a `List<Appointment>` which contains `DateTime Start` and `DateTime End` along with a few others bits.

I want to draw a day planner which lists all of the appointments in order with placeholders/gaps where appropriate.

I have managed this, but now I need to handle the scenario where appointments overlap. It seems this could be;

- appointment a starts before and ends after appointment b
- appointment a starts before and ends during appointment b
- appointment a starts during and end after appointment b
- appointment a start during and ends during appointment b

This feels like a problem which must have been tackled before. Any pointers?

Here's an example of some horrendous code i'm currently working on;

```
        List<TechActivityModel> techActivity = new TechService().GetTechActivity(7, new DateTime(2018, 4, 11), new DateTime(2018, 4, 11).AddDays(1))
            .OrderBy(t => t.Start).ToList();

        for (int i = techActivity.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            //something starts before and ends after
            TechActivityModel clash = techActivity.Where(t => t.Id != techActivity[i].Id && t.Start < techActivity[i].Start && t.End > techActivity[i].End).FirstOrDefault();
            while (clash != null)
            {
                //split the clashing activity into a task before and another task after the existing on
                //first create the 2nd part of the task (after the existing one)
                TechActivityModel activityContinued = new TechActivityModel()
                {
                    Start = techActivity[i].End,
                    End = clash.End,
                    Subject = "++" + clash.Subject
                };
                activityContinued.Length = (int)(activityContinued.End - activityContinued.Start).TotalMinutes;
                techActivity.Add(activityContinued);

                //update the clashing task to finish when the existing task starts
                clash.Subject = "+" + clash.Subject;
                clash.End = techActivity[i].Start;
                clash.Length = (int)(clash.End - clash.Start).TotalMinutes;

                clash = techActivity.Where(t => t.Id != techActivity[i].Id && t.Start < techActivity[i].Start && t.End > techActivity[i].End).FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }

        for (int i = techActivity.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            //something starts before and ends during
            TechActivityModel clash = techActivity.Where(t => t.Id != techActivity[i].Id && t.Start <= techActivity[i].Start && t.End > techActivity[i].Start).FirstOrDefault();
            while (clash != null)
            {
                //update the clashing task to finish when the existing task starts
                clash.Subject = "/" + clash.Subject;
                clash.End = techActivity[i].Start;
                clash.Length = (int)(clash.End - clash.Start).TotalMinutes;

                clash = techActivity.Where(t => t.Id != techActivity[i].Id && t.Start < techActivity[i].Start && t.End > techActivity[i].Start).FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }

        techActivity = techActivity.OrderBy(t => t.Start).ToList();

        //now we're going to pad all the gaps
        List<TechActivityModel> newList = new List<TechActivityModel>();

        DateTime LastEnd = techActivity[0].End;

        //start with the gap from midnight till the first task
        newList.Add(new TechActivityModel()
        {
            Start = new DateTime(2018, 4, 10),
            End = techActivity[0].Start,
            TicketNumber = 0,
            Note = "",
            TicketSubject = "",
            TimeLogged = 0,
            Id = 0
        }
        );

        //pad all the gaps
        for (int i = 1; i < techActivity.Count; i++)
        {
            if (LastEnd < techActivity[i].Start.AddMinutes(-2))
            {
                TechActivityModel gap = new TechActivityModel()
                {
                    Start = LastEnd.AddMinutes(1),
                    End = techActivity[i].Start,
                    Subject = "",
                    Id = 0
                };
                gap.Length = (int)(gap.End - gap.Start).TotalMinutes;
                newList.Add(gap);
            }
            LastEnd = techActivity[i].End;
        }

        //and finally fill the gap from the last task till midnight
        newList.Add(new TechActivityModel()
        {
            Start = LastEnd,
            End = new DateTime(2018, 4, 11),
            Subject = "",
            Length = 0
        }
        );

        newList.AddRange(techActivity);

        string content = "";
        foreach (TechActivityModel techActivityModel in newList.OrderBy(t => t.Start))
        {
            content += 
                techActivityModel.Start.ToShortTimeString() 
                + " - " + techActivityModel.End.ToShortTimeString() 
                + " (" + techActivityModel.Length + "mins)"
                + " : " + techActivityModel.Subject 
                + Environment.NewLine;
        }
```

Comment: People often end up trying to enumerate *cases* for overlaps and miss the obvious. Two time periods overlap if period `a` starts before period `b` ends and period `b` starts before period `a` ends. That's it. One rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd approach you problem, if I understand you correctly. I'd start by finding all of the distinct `Start` and `End` values, all together in a single list. We want them distinct and in order. Then we zip that list with itself to generate pairs:

```
var l = new List<Appointment>();
var ex = l.SelectMany(a => new[] { a.Start, a.End }).Distinct().OrderBy(dt => dt);
var pairs = ex.Zip(ex.Skip(1), (First, Second) => new { First, Second });
```

Now, using the rule I mentioned in the comments:

> Two time periods overlap if period `a` starts before period `b` ends and period `b` starts before period `a` ends.

We work through each pair of datetimes and re-query our appointments list for *all* appointments that overlap the period described by the pair. If you get no results, this time period is currently free. If you get one result, you have (for this period) an appointment that's not overlapped by anything else. If you get multiple results, you have a clash and can work out how to display that. But note that you don't have to keep *revisiting* this time period and extending/shortening it, updating its text, etc.

Comment: Nice technique. Still some work to do, but this does simplify things- thanks

Comment: @LeeTickett - yeah, there are some further optimization opportunities too. Unfortunately, there are two that are mutually exclusive but both work in similar ways - you can sort your `Appointment`s list. If you sort by the `Start` values, then during the search phase you can abandon the search as soon as you hit one with a `Start` greater than your current pair's `End`. The opposite is to sort by `End` values. In that case, before you start each search, you first cull anything from the start of the list that now comes definitely before the current pair.